# How to strip a string with a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to find all the negative floating point numbers in a string and store them in an array. I think my regex is correct, but something is wrong with my method.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]*[.][0-9]+$");      
String[] results = pattern.split("|AAA--A A05_#A| |-999.999| |-55.7|");
```

Comment: Not an answer, but note that it (regex) will not match [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for your float numbers (which are usually acceptable and recognized as floating point numbers) - it might be what you want though.

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is a good website to help you build Regex Expressions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex anchors the match to the end of the string, which isn't what you want.

Likewise, `Pattern.split` doesn't do what you want. Here's some sample code to get you going:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]*[.][0-9]+");
String text = "|AAA--A A05_#A| |-999.999| |-55.7|";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

This prints:

```
-999.999
-55.7
```

Obviously you could add to a list or something similar within the `while` loop. I don't know of any method which returns a collection of all the matches, but you could easily write a utility method to do that yourself, based on code like the above.

EDIT: As noted in comments, if you *only* want to find negative values, the `-` shouldn't be optional (and it doesn't need to be in a set, either - just `-?` would have been fine).

Comment: Why is the "-" optional? This will match positive numbers and she says she needs negatives.

Comment: @Ixx: I don't know, to be honest - that was in the original regex, and I only wanted to adjust it enough to get it working to start with. Will note that in an edit.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks, i finally made it work. Actually i also needed the regex to detect non decimals, so i made the decimal part optional. It works great now :)